# How do I open a url on a background process in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning my way around python and Django, and can't seem to find clear documentation for firing off a background process or thread, to perform some data processing (including pulling info from external websites/urls).

Where can I learn more about background processes/threads in Django?

I'm especially interested in tutorials that demo pulling and pushing data across multiple sites/servers/protocols.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), a task queue that works well with Django.  Add a delayed task in your view and Celery will handle it in a separate process.  Tutorials are available on the Celery homepage.

Once you understand how to create tasks and add tasks to the queue, then you can use standard Python modules like urllib2 to open URLs, or other specialized modules to work with REST APIs.

Under no circumstances should you try to create a new thread or start a subprocess in a view function.  Always use delayed task management.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Python subprocesses (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html :

```
                  subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Comment: The parent process will die as soon as the view function returns.  You should always use delayed task management instead of subprocesses or threads for doing background work in a web framework.